# Abstracting a call to combine the results of a vector of classes

Tags: c++, c++11

I've got a class which acts as a combiner of a vector of pointers to an abstract base class. In the combined class there is a lot of repetition of the function that is used to combine the member functions together, e.g.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual double foo1(double x) = 0;
    virtual double foo2(double x) = 0;
};

class Combined : public Base {
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Base> > bases;

public:
    double foo1(double x) {
        double rv = 0.0;
        for( auto& b : bases ) {
            rv += b->foo1(x);
        }
        return rv;
    }

    double foo2(double x) {
        double rv = 0.0;
        for( auto& b : bases ) {
            rv += b->foo2(x);
        }
        return rv;
    }
};
```

It feels like I should be able to write one function to abstract that pattern away from having to repeat it for every method, so the Combined could be written in a way such as

```
class Combined : public Base {
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Base> > bases;

public:
    double foo1(double x) {
        return combiner(foo1, x);
    }

    double foo2(double x) {
        return combiner(foo2, x);
    }
};
```

and there would be a combiner function along the lines of

```
double combiner(FuncName f, double x)
{
    double rv = 0.0;
    for( auto& b : bases ) {
        rv += b->f(x);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

To reduce the quantity of boilerplate

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there's a typo on the Base class. should it read foo2 for the second method?

Comment: I don't get what you're actually asking for. I can't spot a difference in the implementation of `foo1()`/`foo2()`. Did you mean to show us, you have that boiler plate code amongst other distinct code in those functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <memory>
    #include <algorithm>

    using namespace std;

    struct iFoo {virtual double foo() const=0;};
    struct A : public iFoo {virtual double foo() const{return 10;}};
    struct B :  public iFoo {virtual double foo() const{return 20;}};

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<iFoo>> foos;//pretend its a member variable i'm lazy

    //pretend its a member function (again, lazy)
    template <typename T,typename K>
    T xform_accumulate(T init,K xformer)
    {
        return std::accumulate(foos.cbegin(),foos.cend(),init,[xformer](T a,const std::unique_ptr<iFoo>& b) {return a+xformer(b);});
    }


    int main()
    {

        foos.push_back(std::unique_ptr<iFoo>(new A()));
        foos.push_back(std::unique_ptr<iFoo>(new B()));

        double x = xform_accumulate( 0.0, [](const std::unique_ptr<iFoo>& x){return x->foo();});

       cout << "Hello World" << x << endl; 

       return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

It's called `std::accumulate` (found in `<numeric>`) and it can do exactly this.